# self parameter is different on functions why?

Tags: python, constructor

I find this example very confusing since they are using two different arguments Why ?

```
class Person:
  def __init__(mysillyobject, name, age):
    mysillyobject.name = name
    mysillyobject.age = age

  def myfunc(abc):
    print("Hello my name is " + abc.name)

p1 = Person("John", 36)
p1.myfunc()
```

Answer (score 5):

The first parameter of an instance method is always a reference to the instance.

As a **convention**, you usually name this parameter **self**, however you are free to give the parameter any other valid name, as shown in the code you posted.

Answer (score 1):

So in python, for instance methods, the first argument is for the instance of the class. As mentioned in other answers, this is the **self** argument. But this is only by convention. You can go with anything from `bananas` to `mysillyobject`.

Thus, in your class, the myfunc() method is defined to take only one argument, which is the instance I mentioned earlier.

Hence, when you call myfunc() from p1 (where p1 is the object of the class Person), you are implicitly passing p1 for the argument `abc` mentioned in the definition :

```
def myfunc(abc): # p1 is passed for abc
    print("Hello my name is " + abc.name)
```

Thus, p1.name is accessed and printed to give a proper output